# How do I install a Windows Service created with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, windows-services, command-prompt

I'm creating a Windows service, using [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/naresh.avari/develop-and-install-a-windows-service-in-C-Sharp/) as guidance.

In the "Installing the Windows Service" section, it says to "*Go to "Start" >> "All Programs" >> "Microsoft Visual Studio 2012" >> "Visual Studio Tools" then click "Developer Command Prompt for VS2012*".

First, I thought that strange because it seems as if this could/should be done from within Visual Studio itself, rather than going through a side door, however the "Tools" menu in VS 2013 doesn't have a likely-looking candidate. The article talks about VS 2012, and I'm using VS 2013, but thought the process (no pun intended) should be quite similar. IOW, I thought there should be Start" >> "All Programs" >> "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013" >> "Visual Studio Tools" but there's not:

[image]

...and, in fact, I have no "Visual Studio Tools" there, just "Cross Tools" and "Native Tools" thingamajigs.

So what do I need to do to install my Windows service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right that the process would be similar for VS2013, but didn't notice that the naming in the Start menu had changed, removing the "Microsoft" prepended to the previous versions of Visual Studio. So there it is in the "V"s:

[image]

...and then selecting "Visual Studio Tools" opens an Explorer window with the sought-after Developer Command Prompt (for VS2013):

[image]